# Backbone.js - travel itinerary design/storage - Link list

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am displaying a travel itinerary (like one below) using a day model objects as part of Itinerary collection.

Day 1  5 Aug 2012 'Travel to SFO'
Day 2  6 Aug 2012 'Blah Blah' 
Day 3  7 Aug 2012 'Blah Blah' 
Day 4  8 Aug 2012 'Travel back home!'

Question:

1. When I remove say Day 3 from above plan (this is not a issue), I want the Day 4 to be renamed as Day 3 and its date changed to 7th Aug instead of 8th Aug.

What is the best/backbone way to achieve it?

1. When Day 3, is deleted, does it mean that Day 4's index is now reduced by 1? or is the index to access Day 4 remains same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a backbone collection "Days" with the model being "day". so when you delete a model. you refresh the views, which binds with the collection.

Yes, the Day 4's index is reduced by one.

## Edit-1

The Days collection has a function which binds to the delete function of its models.
This function calculates the indexes and the hashes.

Comment: However does it mean that I have to manually change day 4 to day 3 and reduce the date by one day? If its not done then you have a itinerary with day 1,2,4 and one day missing!

Comment: No you dont have to manually change. Have a collection function that binds to the delete event of its models. This collection function will recalculate the index and days

Comment: @NileshKale yup, and if you find the answer useful mark it as the correct answer, if you have more doubts get to me at anand@devbrother.com